# Force UICollectionViewCell resizing after resizing UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In my uicollectionview delegate, i have this code. Basically it is to set the size of the cells based on the colectionview size.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat ratio = 200.0/280.0; // w/h
    CGFloat cellWidth = (collectionView.frame.size.width-50)/4.0;
    CGFloat cellHeight = cellWidth / ratio;

    CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);

    return cellSize;
}
```

How can I force this delegate to run after I change the collectionView frame without reloading the collectionView? One way I think of is manually calling this funtion by looping through all visible cells, but seems way too heavy for something so simple.

HELLLPPPPPP

Comment: The simplest solution you have already added in your question and it is by reloading the collectionView.

Comment: Instead of forcing a delegate you can copy the data of the delegate and add it to a function. Call the function in delegate and wherever you want to call . What do you say?

Comment: After changing your collectionview's frame just put this line and try,
yourCollectionView.dataSouce = self;

Comment: @NiravD I don't want to reload because reloading make user experience bad.

Comment: @User511, I think you don't understand how this delegate works.

Comment: @RahulPatel I tried that, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then try to reloadInputViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution by myself. In order to force this delegate to run again after resizing collectionview, we just need to reload a SINGLE cell. For example, the first cell. Then collectionview will resize all cells automatically.

```
 NSIndexPath *firstItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
            [_cardCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                [_cardCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[firstItem]];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Anyway thanks all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this delegate manually like this :

```
CGSize size = [self collectionView:self.collectionView 
                            layout:self 
            sizeForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: This way means I need to loop thru all cells. I prefer not to do it like that. Thank you.